# In Orbeon xform, How to get selected drop-down label on change of drop-down in a input field

Tags: orbeon

In Orbeon xform, how to get selected drop-down label on change of drop-down in an [input field](https://github.com/vikash315/Issue/issues/1).

I am able to get drop-down value but not it's label name. Please share ideas about how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

To access the label, you need to use an Orbeon extension function, [`xxf:itemset()`](http://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xpath/extension-controls.html#xxfitemset), which returns the current itemset for a given selection control. For instance, if your control id is `my-select`, you would call:

```
xxf:itemset('my-select', 'xml', true())/itemset/choices/item[@selected = 'true']/label
```

Comment: Pavan, I'm surprised. Maybe make sure that if your control is named `my-dropdown`, you call the function with `xxf:itemset('my-select-control', 'xml', true())`. Note the added `-control`.

Comment: Avernet, I used my control ID itself. Is there anything that I have to do? 
I'm using Dynamic Dropdown

Comment: Hi Pavan, `xxf:itemset()` doesn't work with XBL controls, like the dynamic dropdown; it only works with "plain" XForms controls. This is because right now the XForms engine doesn't know that a particular XBL control is a "selection control" and thus has an itemset. We have an [RFE for this](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/768), and I've added a +1 from you.

Comment: Since Orbeon Forms 4.8 (and 4.7.1), this works with some XBL components at least. See [xxf:itemset() not working anymore now that we use fr:dropdown-select1 #1856](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1856). And so it *should* work with `databound-select1.xbl` as well.

Comment: Hi Avernet, Thanks

Comment: HI  ebruchez, 
will check & let you know. Thanks